# R names function on csv returning generic column signifiers ("V1" "V2" etc.)

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to load a csv file into R and use the column headers in the file to manipulate the data:

```
df <- read.csv(file.path("relevant", "file", "path", "AESO13Mar2017MeritOrder.csv"), header = FALSE)
names(df)
```

Which returns the following:

```
[1] "V1"  "V2"  "V3"  "V4"  "V5"  "V6"  "V7"  "V8"  "V9"  "V10" "V11" "V12" "V13"
```

These column names are completely fictitious; they are not part of the file and don't show up even when I open it in Notepad. head(df) reveals that the file is being properly parsed and loaded into the df dataframe:

```
  V1           V2      V3          V4     V5   V6  V7   V8          V9
1 HE ImportExport AssetID BlockNumber  Price From  To Size AvailableMW
2  1                 PW01           1 999.99    4   5    1           1
3  1                 EGC1           6 999.99  820 822    2           0
4  1                 ME04           1 999.99    4   6    2           0
5  1                 ME03           1 999.99    4   7    3           0
6  1                 DRW1           1 999.99    3   6    3           0
         V10          V11      V12
1 Dispatched DispatchedMW Flexible
2          N            0        Y
3          N            0        Y
4          N            0        Y
5          N            0        Y
6          N            0        Y
                                                      V13
1                                            OfferControl
2                                      Keyera Partnership
3 Capital Power GP Holdings Inc. ENMAX Energy Corporation
4                           URICA Asset Optimization Ltd.
5                           URICA Asset Optimization Ltd.
6                                      BowArk Energy Ltd.
```

I want to be able to use the usefully-titled column headers ("AssetID" etc.) to do some other analysis on the data. How can I get R to recognize the correct column headers?

Comment: Just change `(..,header=T)`.

Comment: Shoot, based on the documentation I looked up I thought header=TRUE was for weird file headers or something. That fixed it; thanks for the quick response.